# Compilar en python con ícono

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, pyqt4, pyinstaller

Estoy compilando una aplicación en Python, antes de compilar todo perfectamente, pero una vez compilado, los íconos de la barra de tareas y la ventana se pierden, cómo puedo compilar y que el ícono no desaparece de esos lugares, el ícono permanece en el ejecutable pero También quiero que esté en la barra de tareas y en la ventana.

Estoy compilando con esta línea:
pyinstaller go.py -i corazon.ico --noconsole --onefile

Comment: prueba con esto es mucho mas facil: [auto-py-to-exe](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe)

Comment: Hola, está genial la aplicación pero aún sigo sin el ícono en la ventana. :(

Comment: los iconos estan en una carpeta? especifica? si es asi cambia las imagenes base64 conviertes y usas es como parte de la app asi no deberia requerir ningu path!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que usas `pyqt` el problema suele estar en no asignar el icono mediante ese sistema. `Pyinstaller` no sabe donde quieres tu icono.

```
class MainForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/images/Images/Main.ico")) # Aqui añadimos el icono desde una ruta o un archivo de recursos.
        self.setWindowTitle("Titulo de la ventana")
```

`Pyinstaller` solo lo añade al archivo, no a la ventana. A la ventana lo debes añadir tú con código como el que he puesto (Aunque debo admitir que mi código es de `PySide2` pero son esencialmente parecidos).

**También:**

Asegúrate de que la ruta es la correcta. Es decir, después de compilar crea manualmente la carpeta donde deba estar la imagen (ya que compilar el código normalmente no copia/pega tu carpeta de recursos con imágenes, fuentes y demás cosas).

Comment: Hola, justamente tengo ese código en mi programa, como mencioné antes de compilar todo funciona perfecto pero una vez compilado el código no aparece en la barra de tareas ni en la ventana, el ícnono lo tengo en la misma carpeta donde está el archivo principal .py.

Comment: Asegúrate de que la ruta es la correcta. Es decir, después de compilar crea manualmente la carpeta donde deba estar la imagen (ya que compilar el código normalmente no copia/pega tu carpeta de recursos con imágenes, fuentes y demás cosas.

Comment: Cierto tenías razón, funcionó :)